# windows authentication issue with asp.net

Tags: iis, asp.net, windows

i have an asp.net application that uses windows authentication.

however i am having trouble with it:

```
  <location path="default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="mlabs\ksmith"/>
        <allow roles="mlabs\Group2Users" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

when i run it, i am getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' and no extension method 'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 143:            </ItemTemplate>
Line 144:        </asp:FormView>
Line 145:        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
Line 146:            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:qcvalues_testConnectionString %>" 
Line 147:            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [batchinfo]" 

Source File: c:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\EnterData\EnterData\Default.aspx    Line: 145 


Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3623; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618
```

does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think this is related to authentication? It explicitly states your code is at fault.

Comment: @ben great question - because when i remove the authentication it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look like it's related to authentication - the yellow screen of death doesn't even mention authentication, and quite explicitly points to your code.

It mentions SQL so have you got your connection strings set up right?

Alternatively, `SqlDataSource1_Selecting` sounds like an event - are you handling it correctly or have you even declared that method?

In any case, I'd say this is your code at fault, not the authentication mode.